# How to identify currently logged in User Type(Root , Admin or Normal) in Mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have to write a function in objective C which identifies currently logged in user type (root, admin or normal).

I am getting UserName by calling NSFullUserName() .... but Can anyone suggest how to get user type in Objective C...

Thanks....